# Unexpected token when parsing a file - javascript

Tags: javascript

Could someone tell me me what's wrong with this piece of code.

```
var ingredient: {
        "text": text,
        "id": Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + text
    };
```

It's part of a post request and it's causing an error because there's an 'unexpected token' somewhere on the 'id' line. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Assignments to variables are performed with a `=`, and `text` is an undeclared variable.

Comment: Instead of "var ingredient:" use "var ingredient = "

Answer (score 1):

```
var ingredient = {
    "text": text,
    "id": Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + text
};
```

Explanation is-  assignment is done using `=` outside of an object (`{}`) and inside an `object` using `:`.

Comment: Upvoted since it's correct but some explanation would be on it's place here for other newbs (not n00bs) that come around here. assignment is done using `=` outside of an object (`{}`) and inside an object using `:`